# Is there a way to check if the user has either a role or a permission in discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I want to make a command that can be used if the user either has a specific role or permission. Here is what I have right now

```
    @commands.has_role('DJ')
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_guild=True)
    async def _stop(self, ctx: commands.Context):

        ctx.voice_state.songs.clear()

        if ctx.voice_state.is_playing:
            ctx.voice_state.voice.stop()
            await ctx.message.add_reaction('⏹')
```

But this requires both the role and the permission. Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, you could check for any roles that the user may need to run the command:

```
@commands.has_any_role(“Admin Perms”, “DJ”)
```

Which will check if the user only has at least one of these roles

Comment: Thanks but it didn't help. I want to check and allow to execute the command if the user either has the manage_guild permission or the DJ role.

Answer (score 0):

this is a Interesting answer. I have something for you

```
if ctx.author.guild_permissions.manage_messages: #if this returns True the print should run!
            print("You have the manage messages Permission")
```

Hope i could help you.